# Is the phase of an electron wave function arbitrary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In general, people say that a wave function can pick up an arbitrary phase because it has no effect on the expectation value of a dynamical variable. However, in the electron interference experiments, for example, Aharonov-Bohm effect or the formation of quantum well states in thin films, the phase does matter. In Aharonov-Bohm effect, two electron beams have a definite phase difference and in the quanutm  well states of thin films the reflected electron waves all have the same phase factor except for different reflection coefficients. Thus, in terms of electron interference phenomena, the wave function can not have arbitrary phase. Instead, the phase of different wave functions have a definite relation. And this is contrary to the general argument that the phase of a wave function is arbitrary. How to explain the contrary?

Comment: It's the same situation as in classical optics: phases don't matter, phase differences do.

Comment: Thank you! But if the phases of the two electron wave functions are both arbitrary, then the phase difference is also arbitrary. Then there should be no interference. So can we say that the phase of a wave function is arbitrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global phase of the wave function does not matter, as the outcome probabilities are given by the square of the absolute value.

But you misinterpret the Aharonov-Bohm experiment I think - it is the same electron that passes on both sides of a solenoid, causing interference effects on the other side. It's not two electrons. So, there is a single wavefunction and it describes all paths (including their relative phase difference, which is modulated by the magnetic non-zero potential outside the solenoid).

As a side-note, the only reason it would be OK to suggest that two different electrons could be described by two wavefunctions or that the electron in the Aharonov-Bohm experiment has its "own" wavefunction is that in the macroscopic world this is enough (unless the electrons are purposefully entangled). From a strict perspective, the entire universe is described by a single wavefunction (and *its* global phase would be irrelevant :).